# How fast are ctypes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

I just started looking into ctypes and was a little curious on how they work. How does it compare speed wise to the regular C implementation? Will using ctypes in a python program speed it up or slow it down is basically what I am wondering. Thanks!

Comment: This is so depended on the program that this cannot be answered.  If you have code in C and want to add Pyhton to make it faster that answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no "regular C implementation" in most cases. Python data structures are one to three order of magnitudes higher level.

To answer you question "how fast are ctypes in python?" - the answer is "pretty fast".

look at numpy for an idea of it.

Answer (score -1):

If speed is only concern don't use Python, PHP, Perl or other scripting language. Write whatever in C or Assembly. Since these scripting languages are fast enough to build Google, Facebook and Amazon, you will find that they are fast enough for whatever you are thinking about.